# Differential Geometry for Computer Science

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, soft-question, computer-science

I am looking for a good book or other resources on Differential Geometry for Computer Sciences or more specifically Differential Geometry used in Computer Graphics, Geometric Modelling and Mesh Processing.

What I have found so far is this course
http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-13-spring/
but it’s hard to follow as the sound in the lectures is very bad.

My background includes Linear Algebra and the standard Calculus sequence up to some elementary differential geometry. I also have some experience with Geometric Algebra and Geometric Calculus.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/875443/589.